# Store Cells with switch on from a Tableview

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

What I want is to generate a sub-contact using properties form an existing `CNContact` object.
I got the `CNContact` object from `CNContactPickerViewController` and display all properties in a tableview.

The tableviewcell is embedded with switch. I have a preview button on the navigation item, when the button is pressed, if the switch in a property is on, this property should be stored in a new `CNMutableContact`.

**My issue is: If the Contact has too many properties, I cannot get the off-screen properties stored. Is there a way to solve this problem.**

part of the code to get sub-contact:

```
+(CNMutableContact*)newContactWithSelectedFieldInTableView:(UITableView*)tableView FromContact:(CNContact*)contact
```

{
    `CNMutableContact* aContact = [[CNMutableContact alloc]init];`

```
//get all indexPath from tableview
NSMutableArray* indexPathArr = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
NSInteger nSections = [tableView numberOfSections];
for (int j=0; j<nSections; j++) {
    NSInteger nRows = [tableView numberOfRowsInSection:j];
    for (int i=0; i<nRows; i++) {
        NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:i inSection:j];
        [indexPathArr addObject:indexPath];
    }
}
//selected phone numbers
//go through indexPath
for (NSIndexPath* path in indexPathArr)
{
    UITableViewCell* nameCell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:path];
    UISwitch *mySwitch = (UISwitch *)nameCell.accessoryView;
    switch (path.section)
    {
        case basicInfoSection://basic info section (name,company,department,title)
        {
            int row = 0;
            if(path.row==row)
            {
                if(mySwitch.on)
                {
                    aContact.givenName = contact.givenName;
                    aContact.middleName = contact.middleName;
                    aContact.familyName = contact.familyName;
                }
            }
            if(![contact.organizationName isEqualToString:@""])
            {row += 1;
                if(path.row==row)//company row
                {
                    //store company
                    if(mySwitch.on)
                        aContact.organizationName = contact.organizationName;
                }
            }
            if(![contact.departmentName isEqualToString:@""])
            {row += 1;
                if(path.row==row)//department row
                {
                    //store department
                    if(mySwitch.on)
                        aContact.departmentName = contact.departmentName;
                }
            }
            if(![contact.jobTitle isEqualToString:@""])
            {row += 1;
                if(path.row==row)//jobTitle row
                {
                    //store job Title
                    if(mySwitch.on)
                        aContact.jobTitle = contact.jobTitle;
                }
            }
        }
            break;
        case phoneSection:
        {
            if(mySwitch.on)
            {
                aContact.phoneNumbers = [aContact.phoneNumbers arrayByAddingObject:contact.phoneNumbers[path.row]];
            }
        }
            break;
```

**I come up with a solution and it work fine for now, some code are listed below:**

1# create a subclass of UISwitch

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@interface SwitchWithIndex : UISwitch
@property (strong ,nonatomic) NSIndexPath* indexPath;
@end
```

2# create a dictionary that record indexPath with switch state and in view did load, loop datasource(the CNContact) for all possible indexPath according to the demand tableview layout.

```
for(NSInteger section=0; section<7; section++)
{
    switch (section) {
        {
            //section 1 basic info(name, company, department, job title)
        case basicInfoSection:
            {int row =0;
                NSIndexPath* indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:row inSection:section];
                [_switchStateAtIndex setObject:boolNumber forKey:indexPath];

                if(![_contact.organizationName isEqualToString:@""])
                {row += 1;
                    NSIndexPath* indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:row inSection:section];
                    [_switchStateAtIndex setObject:boolNumber forKey:indexPath];
                }
                if(![_contact.departmentName isEqualToString:@""])
                {row += 1;
                    NSIndexPath* indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:row inSection:section];
                    [_switchStateAtIndex setObject:boolNumber forKey:indexPath];
                }
                if(![_contact.jobTitle isEqualToString:@""])
                {row += 1;
                    NSIndexPath* indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:row inSection:section];
                    [_switchStateAtIndex setObject:boolNumber forKey:indexPath];
                }
            }
            break;

            //section 2 phones
        case phoneSection:
            {
                for(NSInteger row=0; row<[_contact.phoneNumbers count];row++)
                {
                    NSIndexPath* indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:row inSection:section];
                    [_switchStateAtIndex setObject:boolNumber forKey:indexPath];
                }
            }
            break; 
 //more code ..
```

3# In Table View Datasource Delegate load the state of switch at indexpath and

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{   UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell"];
SwitchWithIndex* mySwitch = [[SwitchWithIndex alloc] init];
[mySwitch addTarget:self action:@selector(switchChanged:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
NSNumber* switchStateNumber =[_switchStateAtIndex objectForKey:indexPath];
BOOL switchState = [switchStateNumber boolValue];
mySwitch.on = switchState;
mySwitch.indexPath = [[NSIndexPath alloc]init];
mySwitch.indexPath = indexPath;
cell.accessoryView = mySwitch;
//more code
```

and the following code to detect change on switch state.

```
- (void) switchChanged:(id)sender {

SwitchWithIndex* mySwitch = sender;

NSIndexPath* indexPath = mySwitch.indexPath;

NSLog(@"%@",indexPath);

NSNumber* switchStateBool = [NSNumber numberWithBool:mySwitch.on ? YES : NO];

[_switchStateAtIndex setObject:switchStateBool forKey:indexPath];

NSLog( @"The switch is %@", mySwitch.on ? @"ON" : @"OFF" );

}
```

4# And finally save selected field based on switch state

```
+(CNMutableContact*)newContactFrom:(CNContact*)contact withSwitchState:(NSMutableDictionary*)switchState
{
  CNMutableContact* aContact = [[CNMutableContact alloc]init];

for (NSIndexPath* indexPath in switchState.keyEnumerator)
{
    NSNumber* boolNumber = [switchState objectForKey:indexPath];
    BOOL switchOn = [boolNumber boolValue];
    switch (indexPath.section) {
        case basicInfoSection://basic info section (name,company,department,title)
        {
            int row = 0;
            if(indexPath.row==row)
            {
                if(switchOn)
                {
                    aContact.givenName = contact.givenName;
                    aContact.middleName = contact.middleName;
                    aContact.familyName = contact.familyName;
                }
            }
            if(![contact.organizationName isEqualToString:@""])
            {row += 1;
                if(indexPath.row==row)//company row
                {
                    //store company
                    if(switchOn)
                        aContact.organizationName = contact.organizationName;
                }
            }
//more code
```

There may be other solution to solve this issue, above is what I can do for now.

Comment: Are all of the controls stored within a single cell? Or do you have multiple cells for each `CNContact` object, some of which could be off screen?

Comment: @Stonz2 Sorry, I'm not sure what you are asking. I get the CNContact object from CNContactViewPickerController. And for the properties of the contact (phones,emails,urls..) I use UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell"]; and embedded with switch

Comment: Are you saying that you need to get the content/state of multiple cells, some of which could be off screen? Or are all of the things you need in a single really big cell, part of which could be off screen?

Comment: @Stonz2 I need to get the switch(on,off) state of multiple cells, including the cells which are off screen. Is there a way to enumerate all cells in a table view after the view appears.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than enumerating all of the cells in a table view, you need to store the state of the switches somewhere other than in the table view's cells. I would imagine that this is already being done, otherwise the state of the switches would not be reliable/consistent just from scrolling the table view.

For instance, in your `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method, you must tell the cell whether the switch should be displayed as `on` or `off`. You would do this by holding the state of your switches in an instance-level array. Here is one way to do that:

```
@interface YourClass ()
{
    // Create an instance-level array to store switch values.
    NSMutableArray *switchValues;
}

...

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    switchValues = [NSMutableArray new];
    for(int i = 0; i < YOUR_TABLE_SIZE; i++)
        [switchValues insertObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:DEFAULT_SWITCH_STATE]];

    // Alternatively, populate your array with another data object if all the
    // switches do not have the same default starting state (on/off).
}

...

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    YourCustomCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"CellIdentifier" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    ...

    // Add a target to the switch so we know when it toggles.
    [cell.toggleSwitch addTarget:self action:@selector(switchSwitched:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
    cell.toggleSwitch.tag = indexPath.row;
    // Set the state to the appropriate value.
    cell.toggleSwitch.on = [[switchValues objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] boolValue];

    return cell;
}

- (void)switchSwitched:(UISwitch *)switcher
{
    // Toggle the switch's value in the instance array
    [switchValues replaceObjectAtIndex:switcher.tag withObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:switcher.on]];
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, your are right, I need to record my switch's state.     Cause I have several sections of cells and the row for each sections depending the CNContact object, I can not use a tag witch can just pass a integer. My solution is to create a subclass of UISwitch with a NSIndexpath property. The value at a NSIndexpath should be changed when switch turned. And in datasource delegate function, I will load the state of switch at   index path.  I will update some code..

Comment: Correct- the above example would only work for a table with 1 section. It's just to give the general idea of knowing which switch was toggled and saving it somewhere other than in the cell object.

Comment: Thank you @Stonz2, I am new to IOS and it always be great to explore and learn new stuff.